# jquery exclude div from function

Tags: jquery, checkbox, prop

I have some jquery that unchecks all the checkboxes and then if one gets checked then it will uncheck all the others! I want to exclude a div on the page with some checkboxes from this!

The div to be excluded has class="addon"..

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false)
    $('input:checkbox').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);        
        }
    });
})
recal();

});
```

Or how can i make the above code apply to only checkboxes inside a div with a class name of notaddon..instead of all the checkboxes on the page! ???

( EDIT: I actually Butchered the question but Roger gave me exactly what i asked for even tho its not what i meant i gave roger the check! Funny enough it was till i seen Pratik response that i realised i asked the wrong question! so he should get some credit..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

For example I want to get checkbox checked with in a div with class test

**HTML**

```
<div class="test"><input type="checkbox" id="test"/></div>
<input type="checkbox" id="test1"/>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".test input:checkbox").prop('checked', true);
```

Or if I have understood correctly you might want this code of yours

```
 $('.notaddon input:checkbox').prop('checked', false)
    $('.notaddon input:checkbox').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('.notaddon input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);        
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

After this code write another code for all checkbox inside div and uncheck the propeties of checkbox.

`$('#yourExcludeDivID').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').removeAttr('checked');`

if you want to remove the checkbox completely from div then use

`$('#yourExcludeDivID').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').remove();`

Answer (score 0):

`$('input:checkbox', '#myDivId')` will give you all checkboxes contained in a div with `id="myDivId"`

So in your case it would be `$('input:checkbox', '.notaddon')`